# Android Studio java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: R$string

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, jar

I have an Android Studio project and it uses an external library .jar file as dependency.

When I run the app, I run into this error:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/externalibrary/R$string


11-30 17:06:02.475 22610-22610/com.mycompany.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.mycompany.myapp, PID: 22610
                                                                             java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/externalibrary/R$string;
                                                                                 at com.externalibrary.client.externalibrarySettingsManager.getShouldAnnotateBlobs(externalibrarySettingsManager.java:80)
                                                                                 at com.externalibrary.client.externalibrarySettingsManager.getMotionDetectorConfigurationFromPreference(externalibrarySettingsManager.java:39)
                                                                                 at com.externalibrary.client.externalibrarySettingsManager.getConfigurationFromPreference(externalibrarySettingsManager.java:28)
                                                                                 at com.externalibrary.client.externalibraryClient.<init>(externalibraryClient.java:24)
                                                                                 at com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:191)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.externalibrary.R$string" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-2/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                 at com.externalibrary.client.externalibrarySettingsManager.getShouldAnnotateBlobs(externalibrarySettingsManager.java:80) 
                                                                                 at com.externalibrary.client.externalibrarySettingsManager.getMotionDetectorConfigurationFromPreference(externalibrarySettingsManager.java:39) 
                                                                                 at com.externalibrary.client.externalibrarySettingsManager.getConfigurationFromPreference(externalibrarySettingsManager.java:28) 
                                                                                 at com.externalibrary.client.externalibraryClient.<init>(externalibraryClient.java:24) 
                                                                                 at com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:191) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: full exception plz

Comment: updated the question.